How to add scroll function to tabs
Currently I can scroll when click and drag on the margin space between the AriaTabs. Once I click on the AriaTab, it'll register as a click. OnMouseDown and onClick won't be detected when I click on AriaTab. Wrapping AriaTab inside div breaks the entire component.
Are there any way to add scroll functionality on the tabs without scrollbar?
import { Tabs, TabList, Tab as AriaTab, TabPanel } from 'react-aria-components';

const Tab: React.FC<TabProps> = ({ tabs }) => {

  const tabsRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [ isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown ] = useState(false);
  const [ startX, setStartX ] = useState(0);
  const [ scrollLeft, setScrollLeft ] = useState(0);

  const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    console.log('handleMouseDown registered');
    if (tabsRef.current) {
      setIsMouseDown(true);
      setStartX(e.pageX - tabsRef.current.offsetLeft);
      setScrollLeft(tabsRef.current.scrollLeft);
    }
  };
  const handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>)=> {
    if(!isMouseDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (tabsRef.current) {
      const x = e.pageX - tabsRef.current.offsetLeft;
      const walk = (x-startX)*2;
      tabsRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeft-walk;
    }
  }
  const handleMouseMoveCapture = ()=> {
    console.log('handleMouseMoveCapture');
  }
  const handleMouseUp = ()=> {
    setIsMouseDown(false);
  }
  const handleMouseLeave = ()=> {
    setIsMouseDown(false);
  }
 
  const handleTabClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const tabElement = e.target as HTMLElement;
    console.log('handleTabClick')
    if (tabElement.closest(`.${styles['react-aria-Tab']}`)) {
      console.log(`Tab ${tabElement.innerText} clicked`);
    }
  };

  return (
      <Tabs className={styles['react-aria-Tabs']}>
        <div className={styles['scrolling-container']} 
          ref={tabsRef}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
          onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
          onMouseMoveCapture={handleMouseMoveCapture}
          onClick={handleTabClick}
        >
        <TabList className={styles['react-aria-TabList']}>
           {tabs.map(tab => (          
            <AriaTab key={tab.id} id={tab.id} className={styles['react-aria-Tab']}>
              {tab.icon && <span className={styles['react-aria-TabIcon']}>{tab.icon}</span>}
              {tab.label}
            </AriaTab>
          ))}              
          </TabList>
          </div>
        {tabs.map(tab => (
          <TabPanel key={tab.id} id={tab.id} className={styles['react-aria-TabPanel']}>
            {tab.content}
          </TabPanel>
        ))}
      </Tabs>
  );
};


Add scroll to tabs:
import { Tabs, TabList, Tab as AriaTab, TabPanel } from 'react-aria-components';

const Tab = ({ tabs }) => {
  const tabsRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    if (tabsRef.current) {
      tabsRef.current.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.pageX;
      tabsRef.current.dataset.scrollLeft = tabsRef.current.scrollLeft;
    }
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!tabsRef.current || !tabsRef.current.dataset.mouseDownAt) return;
    const mouseDelta = tabsRef.current.dataset.mouseDownAt - e.pageX;
    tabsRef.current.scrollLeft = tabsRef.current.dataset.scrollLeft - mouseDelta;
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    if (tabsRef.current) {
      delete tabsRef.current.dataset.mouseDownAt;
      delete tabsRef.current.dataset.scrollLeft;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Tabs className="react-aria-Tabs">
      <div
        className="scrolling-container"
        ref={tabsRef}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseUp}
      >
        <TabList className="react-aria-TabList">
          {tabs.map(tab => (
            <AriaTab key={tab.id} id={tab.id} className="react-aria-Tab">
              {tab.icon && <span className="react-aria-TabIcon">{tab.icon}</span>}
              {tab.label}
            </AriaTab>
          ))}
        </TabList>
      </div>
      {tabs.map(tab => (
        <TabPanel key={tab.id} id={tab.id} className="react-aria-TabPanel">
          {tab.content}
        </TabPanel>
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Tab;

Scroll work when drag mouse. No scrollbar need.

Thanks, but this does not work for me
